# how display with pagination CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

controller :

```
function my_feeds()
    {   
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->get_my_feeds();
        if($query->num_rows()>0) {
            $res = $query->result();
            $this->load->view('my_feed',array("query"=>$res));
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No feeds added";
        }
```

Model:

```
function get_my_feeds()
    {
        $this->db->where('username',$this->session->userdata('username'));
        $q = $this->db->get('feeds');
        return $q;
    }
```

View:

```
<ol><?php
foreach ($query as $row){
     echo "<li><a href='".$row->url."'>".$row->title."</a></li><br/>";
};?>
```

With controller i retrieve data from my database and display thems in the view. I try to make a pagination. I put this code in the if statement on the controller function.

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
                $this->load->library('table');
                $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Codeigniter/index.php/site/my_feeds';
                $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
                $config['per_page'] = 10;
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

I don't know how to connect the results with the pagination and  how to show both in my view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Controller

```
function my_feeds()
    {   
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $query = $this->membership_model->get_my_feeds();

       $this->load->library('pagination');
                $this->load->library('table');
                $config['base_url']='http://localhost/Codeigniter/index.php/site/my_feeds';
                $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
                $config['per_page'] = 10;
                $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        if($query->num_rows()>0) {
            $res = $this->membership_model->get_my_feeds($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
            $this->load->view('my_feed',array("query"=>$res));
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No feeds added";
        }
    }
```

Model

```
 function get_my_feeds($limit = 0,$offset = 0)
    {
        $this->db->where('username',$this->session->userdata('username'));
        if ($limit != 0)
          $this->db->limit($limit,$offset)
        $q = $this->db->get('feeds');
        return $q;
    }
```

in view page just add this line where you want to show pagination links..

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Comment: it gives this error :Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/my_feed.php

Comment: is it in the same line number as 

`<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>`

Comment: what do you mean with first name? in first line?

Comment: it the line in the foreach statement echo "<li><a href='".$row->url."'>".$row->title."</a></li><br/>";

Comment: just remove that line ..i cant see why u have added it ?

Comment: the pagination appears but it appears error for each row retrieved 1.error Trying to get property of non-object Filename: views/my_feed.php 2.same error. etc..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48565/discussion-between-user3313651-and-bad-developer)

Comment: have u declered the `$row` object before using it ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution if you're willing to rewrite the db queries is this: use PDO and fetch the data as objects of a `FeedEntry` class stored in a `FeedEntryList`, which implements `Iterator` interface. Code a function for `FeedEntryList` that renders the actual page results, for example `FeedEntryList::render(1,10)` should return an array of `FeedEntry` objects (1st page, 10 feeds), which you can easily show using a `foreach`.